# CVRP optimizer send two vehicles to same location (nonoptimal solution)?

Tags: optaplanner

I have been using opta planner to optimize a simple CVRP problem, I have (2) vehicles with capacity (5) and (3) customers, two of them in same location.

Those two customers have combined demand of 5 and the third has a demand of 2.

The issue is that result have both vehicles visit the location with two customers, each one serves one customer.

Shouldn't the optimizer send one vehicle to 2 customers in same location and and the other to the third.

It should be noted that I used CustomerNearbyDistanceMeter for move selector, but same result.

Thank you,

Comment: How about distance between this locations. Maybe distance depo - A - B -depo is shorter than depo - B - depo, where B is location with single customer. For example depo -10km- A -2km- B -20km depo = 32 km vs depo -20km- B -20km- depo = 40km

Comment: @Mateusz M Thank you, actually the result is better, meaning it has less distance covered by vehicles. My bad